# Combine two columns to a datetime in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
df.head(6):

year    qtr    measure
1990     3   1.813619
1990     4   1.809598
1991     1   1.814911
1991     2   1.808807
1991     3   1.820009
...
```

How could I possibly combine 'year' and 'qtr' to get a datetime column in pandas? It can be just the end date of the quarter.

Thanks.

Comment: can u add little code how ur getting year and qtr into dataframe ..is it like this d = {'year': yearlist, 'qtr': quaterlist,'measure':measurelist} if u provide little more code v can solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version  (as long as you have numpy >= 1.7):

```
df['date'] = (np.array(df.year.astype(str),dtype='datetime64[Y]') 
              + np.array(df.qtr*3,dtype='timedelta64[M]')
              - np.timedelta64(1,'D'))

print df
   year  qtr   measure       date
0  1990    3  1.813619 1990-09-30
1  1990    4  1.809598 1990-12-31
2  1991    1  1.814911 1991-03-31
3  1991    2  1.808807 1991-06-30
4  1991    3  1.820009 1991-09-30

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Edit: Added an Explanation:**

So first I make a datetime64 numpy array out of the year column:

```
print (np.array(df.year.astype(str),dtype='datetime64[Y]')

['1990' '1990' '1991' '1991' '1991']
```

These are datetime64 dtypes at the year level so if we add a month to the first date, it will be '1990-01' + 1 month. So adding the qtr*3 will create a YYYY-MM date that is one month too far:

```
print (np.array(df.year.astype(str),dtype='datetime64[Y]') 
       + np.array(df.qtr*3,dtype='timedelta64[M]'))

['1990-10' '1991-01' '1991-04' '1991-07' '1991-10']
```

So if I subtract off one day from '1990-10', I will get to the previous month end (which is the month end you want):

```
print (np.array(df.year.astype(str),dtype='datetime64[Y]') 
      + np.array(df.qtr*3,dtype='timedelta64[M]')
      - np.timedelta64(1,'D'))

['1990-09-30' '1990-12-31' '1991-03-31' '1991-06-30' '1991-09-30']
```

Comment: Thank you! Very smart way.     Do you care to explain why you are using np.timedelta64(1,'D'), but got the end of month date?

Comment: Yep, I just edited my answer to include an explanation.